# Angular PayPal Shipping Price

Tags: angular, typescript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I created an e-commerce website and the receipt only prints out the total payment of the items. I have also tried looking if there was an SDK for Angular or TypeScript PayPal, but I was only able to find one for JavaScript which didn't work for my Angular code. I would like to make the shipping cost 5.00 for example. What way(s) could I include the shipping price to Angular PayPal?

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CartService } from 'src/app/service/service.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IPayPalConfig, ICreateOrderRequest, IOnShippingChangeData } from 'ngx-paypal';
import emailjs, { EmailJSResponseStatus, init } from '@emailjs/browser';
init("user_66nwzX6xZ5j1WCaDKBM51");

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.scss']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

  public payPalConfig ? : IPayPalConfig;
  public products : any = [];
  public grandTotal !: number;
  paymentHandler: any = null;
  showSuccess: boolean | undefined;
  
  constructor(private cartService : CartService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(res=>{
      this.products = res;
      this.grandTotal = this.cartService.getTotalPrice();
    })
  }

  totalItemPayment(quantity: number, price: number){
    return quantity * price;
  }

  removeItem(item: any){
    this.cartService.removeCartItem(item);
  }

  emptycart(){
    this.cartService.removeAllCart();
  }

  checkout(){
    const myValue: any = this.grandTotal.toFixed(2);
    console.log("total price (value) = " + myValue);
    let text = JSON.stringify(this.cartService.cartItemList);
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(text);
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++)
      {
        const description = "quantity: " + jsonObj[i]['quantity'] + "\ntitle: " + jsonObj[i]['title'] + "\n\n";
      }
    
    const title: string[] = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++){
      title.push(jsonObj[i]['quantity'] + " " + jsonObj[i]['title']);
    }
    
    var moo = JSON.stringify(title);
    console.log(moo);
    
    this.payPalConfig = {
      currency: 'USD',
      clientId: "[type in your client-id]",
      //@ts-ignore
      createOrderOnClient: (data) => <ICreateOrderRequest>{
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            currency_code: 'USD',
            value: myValue,
            breakdown: {
              item_total: {
                currency_code: 'USD',
                value: myValue
              }
            },
          },
          description: moo,
        }]
      },
      advanced: {
        commit: 'true'
      },
      style: {
        label: 'paypal',
        layout: 'vertical'
      },
      onApprove: (data, actions) => {
        console.log('onApprove - transaction was approved, but not authorized', data, actions);
        actions.order.get().then((details: any) => {
          console.log('onApprove - you can get full order details inside onApprove: ', details);
        });
      },
      onClientAuthorization: (data) => {
        console.log('onClientAuthorization - you should probably inform your server about completed transaction at this point', data);
        this.showSuccess = true;
       // empties cart after user purchases
        this.emptycart();
      },
      onCancel: (data, actions) => {
        console.log('OnCancel', data, actions);
      },
      onError: err => {
        console.log('OnError', err);
      },
      onClick: (data, actions) => {
        console.log('onClick', data, actions);
      },
      onShippingChange: (data, actions) => {
        return actions.resolve() // or .reject()
      },
    };

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the API, but looking at the documentation and example (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-paypal) would adding an `items` sub array to your `purchase-units` produce the desired results?

```
....
items: [{
                        name: 'Enterprise Subscription',
                        quantity: '1',
                        category: 'DIGITAL_GOODS',
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: 'EUR',
                            value: '9.99',
                        },
                    }]
....
```